# .htaccess 301 redirects not working for some users

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I moved an old website to a new domain. Therefore i made a 301 redirect for a every page of the old website to the corresponding page of the new website to preserve pagerank and SEO. Everything works. I also made the old website still visible for our IP address, which is `91.187.222.26`, because we want to access the old website to save all texts, pictures and stuff.

Today we got some calls of customers (outside our buildings) who can still see the old website. How can this be possible? I checked with many different IPs (proxy, 3G, home, office, other countries) and they all properly redirect.

Here is the `.htaccess` file put in `autodromodifranciacorta.com` root:

```
#autodromodifranciacorta.com

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


#ALL THE PAGES REDIRECTED
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^autodromo-la-struttura/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/strutture/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^autodromo-la-struttura/la-struttura/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/strutture/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^autodromo-la-struttura/modulistica-generale/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/modulistica-e-regolamenti/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^autodromo-la-struttura/partner-sponsor/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/partners/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^circuito-auto/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/strutture/pista-asfaltata/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^circuito-auto/la-pista/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/strutture/pista-asfaltata/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^circuito-auto/prove-libere-auto/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/prove-libere/prove-libere-auto-racing/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^circuito-auto/prove-libere-moto/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/prove-libere/prove-libere-moto/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^circuito-auto/info-e-costi/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/listino-prezzi/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^corsi/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/corsi/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^corsi/corsi-in-pista/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/corsi/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^corsi/guida-sicura/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/corsi/corsi-di-guida-sicura-aci/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^corsi/guida-sicura/guida-sicura-auto/guida-sicura-auto-base/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/corsi/corsi-di-guida-sicura-aci/corsi-di-guida-sicura-aci-base/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^corsi/guida-sicura/guida-sicura-auto/guida-sicura-auto-avanzato/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/corsi/corsi-di-guida-sicura-aci/corsi-di-guida-sicura-aci-avanzato/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^corsi/guida-sicura/guida-sicura-auto/guida-sicura-auto-difensiva/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/corsi/corsi-di-guida-sicura-aci/corsi-di-guida-sicura-auto-difensiva/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^corsi/guida-sicura/guida-sicura-auto/guida-sicura-auto-safe-fun/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/corsi/corsi-di-guida-sicura-aci/corso-di-guida-safe-fun/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^corsi/guida-sicura/mezzi-pesanti-motrici-e-bilici/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/corsi/corsi-di-guida-sicura-aci/corsi-di-guida-sicura-mezzi-pesanti/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^corsi/corsi-in-pista/corsi-auto/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/corsi/corsi-di-guida-sportiva-pista/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^corsi/corsi-in-pista/moto/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/corsi/riding-school-di-luca-pedersoli/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^corsi/fuori-strada/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/corsi/corsi-di-guida-off-road/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^corsi/corsi-in-pista/moto/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/corsi/riding-school-di-luca-pedersoli/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^corsi/modulistica-corsi/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/corsi/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^calendario/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/calendario/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^category/calendario/prove-libere-moto/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/calendario/prove-libere-moto/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^category/calendario/prove-libere-auto/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/calendario/prove-libere-auto-racing/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^category/calendario/racing-gare/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/calendario/gare-moto/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^category/calendario/guida-sicura/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/calendario/corsi-di-guida-sicura-aci-calendario/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^category/calendario/ospitalita/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/calendario/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^category/calendario/drive-accademy/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/calendario/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^category/calendario/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/calendario/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^category/archivio-news/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/news/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^category/archivio-news/drive-academy-news/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/news/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^category/archivio-news/guida-sicura-news/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/news/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^category/archivio-news/ospitalita-news/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/news/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^category/archivio-news/prove-libere-auto-e-moto-news/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/news/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^category/archivio-news/racing-gare-news/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/news/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^galleria-video/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/foto-e-video/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^photogallery/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/foto-e-video/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^info/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/contatti/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteRule ^info/dove-siamo/$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/contatti/ [R=301,L]

#REDIRECT EVERYTHING ELSE
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.autodromodifranciacorta.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.autodromodifranciacorta.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.187\.222\.26
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^autodromodifranciacorta.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://franciacortacircuit.com/ [R=301,L]

#CONTROLLA CHE ANCHE en.autodromodifranciacorta.com redirezioni a franciacortacircuit.com



#WORDPRESS STUFF
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Here are some additional data:

1. Old website: http://autodromodifranciacorta.com
2. New website: http://franciacortacircuit.com/

## HYPOTHESIS

Is it possible that all the people that can still see the old website have the same IP address that we have? Maybe they are in the same (small) city and have the same provider...

Comment: Because i want the old website to be accessible only for one client/user, which is 91.187.222.26 while all the other clients must be redirected to the new one. That's why every rule has that condition, because i want everyone to be redirected except me, which is the user with that IP.

Comment: Ok after reading the OP again, I see that. Now, the redirect seems to work for me. The only thing I can think of would be cache. But I wouldn't think it would hang around after the rules are updated.

Comment: Which kind of cache? A server side cache i suppose, being .htaccess on the server. How can i check whether there's such kind of cache? I use LAMP + Wordpress.

Comment: client side. Sometimes browsers such as Chrome will cache those rules especially with 301's. I have the problem when testing rewrites. So to make sure my rules are working I open dev tools network tab and click `disable cache` while the tool is open.

Comment: Thanks i couldn't imagine 301 could be cached too! Is there a way to tell the browser to follow the new rules, like a command to add to .htaccess?